# Logging service for a visual studio C# custom action

Tags: visual-studio, logging, installation, custom-action

To help isolate problems that may occur when users try to use my installer, I have decided to log installation progress, states, errors, and warnings in a log file from my custom actions.  However, none of the popular logging packages seem to be viable since they require configuration of the calling assembly (log4net for example).  And I have also read that you cannot do MSI logging through Installer classes after trying and failing.  For now I can simply resort to basic file operations to log the information.  Is this what most people do who write custom actions with logs, or is there a another way I have not considered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, my installer ended up needing an external ui handler.  This caused me to switch from setup & deployment to wix/votive for my MSI needs.  As a result the DTF custom actions were able to use MSI logging.

Answer (score 0):

I like the Windows Event Log myself.

[`System.Diagnostics.EventLog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx)